# Login loop both from GUI and console

Tags: command-line, 22.04, login-screen

Whenever I try to login to my Ubuntu desktop, it asks for login in a loop.
I tried to login from console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), but it's also not working. Console also asks for login in a loop. Now I am unable to login.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What were the changes you made to your system since the last time login worked? You can hold the Shift key as you boot, and get into "single user mode" (that single user is `root`), and `mv` your user's `.bashrc` startup file (`mv /home/youruserid/.bashrc /home/youruserid/.bashrc.bad`) out of the way. `exit` single user mode, and try to login. When that works, do `bash -x ~/.bashrc.bad` to debug.